# How to delete all hidden rows EPPlus C# excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I have an excel sheet with hidden rows and I wrote a code to try and delete those rows using EPPlus, but this code doesn't delete all the hidden rows - it appears that it misses some rows randomly.

Any idea why?

```
var start = loadedWorksheet.Dimension.Start;
var end = loadedWorksheet.Dimension.End;

for (int row = start.Row; row <= end.Row; row++)
            {
                if (loadedWorksheet.Row(row).Hidden == true)
                {
                    loadedWorksheet.DeleteRow(row);
                }
            }

            loadedExcelPackage.Save();
```

Comment: Are some of the rows filtered? It could be that they appear hidden but aren't really hidden but filtered.

Comment: @RyanWilson for testing purposes I am not using a filtered file, but when I finish the program I will be dealing with filtered excel sheets... So I may have to go back to the drawing board on this

Comment: Forgive me if I am missing something, however, it appears to me that you may have a possible loop issue. The code gets the `start` and `end` variables to loop through the worksheet. However, it appears to me, that “deleting” a row from the “collection you are looping through” may be problematic. In addition to delete rows, you should delete the rows from the bottom up. If you delete from top to bottom, then it would not be surprising to see skipped rows and/or a possible out of bounds exception. Just a heads up.

Comment: @JohnG Sir, thank you so much for the help. I did what you said and made the loop so it deletes from the bottom up and it fixed it. If you want to put this as the solution please do and I will accept it as the answer.